# Multiprocessing Python Pool

Tags: python, python-2.7, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

When is it necessary to call `.join()` and `.close()` on a `Pool` in the case below? Reading the docs, it looks like it is for waiting for the processes to finish. For instance, if I do something like this:

```
while True:
    pool = Pool(processes=4)
    results = []
    for x in range(1000):
        result = pool.apply_async(f, (x,))
        results.append(result)

    for result in results:
        result.get(timeout=1)
    print "finished"
```

Do I still need to wait for the other process to finish with `join()` and `close()`? As I assume, that since I am iterating over all async results and waiting (blocking) for them to finish, by the time I get to `print finished`, all processes will have exited already?

Is this correct?

Also when do the processes start working on a function? I noticed that there are 4 processes running in parallel with `ps -elf`. Do the processes only start to work on the function after `result.get()` is called in this case?

Answer (score 0):

> close()
>
> Prevents any more tasks from being submitted to the pool. Once all the tasks have been completed the worker processes will exit.
>
> join()
>
> Wait for all processes to properly terminate

Good link to start with [Proper way to use multiprocessor.Pool in a nested loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20387510/proper-way-to-use-multiprocessor-pool-in-a-nested-loop)

As soon as you call `pool.apply_async` the process will start working on the function, it'll return a result object